# Is the text box control source and/or function call syntax invalid or is this a MS Access bug? Is there a workaround?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

I have a function that works fine when called within VBA regardless of what arguments I pass values to or do not pass values to.

The function also works when called from the control source of a text box on a continuous form so long as I pass values to all arguments.

The error occurs when changing the control source of the text box so that a value is not passed to the first optional argument. Specifically when trying to click out of either of those fields. So in other words it won't let me save the control source change as it thinks the syntax is wrong.The error occurs whether I change the control source using the property sheet or by typing within the text box.

I have tried specifying ByVal for the arguments and not using default values for the optional arguments but that did not work. I verified that the function is public and that there are no misspellings or data type mismatches. It definitely has something to do with the syntax when not passing a value to the first optional argument. (the two commas next to each other)

Control source that works:

```
=GetProfile(Nz([FieldName],0),"",Forms("FormName"))
```

Control source that causes error:

```
=GetProfile(Nz([FieldName],0),,Forms("FormName"))
```

The error is:
"The expression you entered contains invalid syntax. You may have entered a comma without a preceding value or identifier."

The function is listed below and it is within a module, not a class module. I simplified the guts of the function for brevity:

```
Public Function GetProfile(varPerson as Variant, Optional strLName as string = "", Optional frm as Access.Form = Nothing) as string
GetProfile = "Test"
End Function
```

I am pretty sure this is a bug. Can someone confirm or point out my mistake? If it is a bug, is there a work around?

Comment: I see the same behavior in Access 2010.  I would use the workaround you already found --- supply `""` for the function's second argument.  Why is that unacceptable?

Comment: I wanted to ensure I was not overlooking a mistake on my part. I appreciate you reviewing my work. I will continue utilizing the work around we identified. Thank you.